# Control Stepper via Serial Monitor

Tags: stepper

I would like to control my stepper via serial monitor and unfortunatley the code below did not work. Serial monitor works (Serial.println()), but it does not execute the stepperOne() part. Any ideas why would be awesome. 
Thank you.

```
#include <AccelStepper.h>

const int stepPin = 5;
const int dirPin = 4;
const int enPin = 12;

String msg;

unsigned int DEST = 800;
unsigned int SPD = 1600;
unsigned int ACCEL = 1600;
const int TEST = 3;

void setup() {

  pinMode(stepPin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dirPin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enPin,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(enPin,HIGH);
  Serial.begin(9600);  // Start Serial

}

void loop() {

if (Serial.available()>0) {
    msg = "";
    while (Serial.available()) {
      delay(10);
      char tmp = Serial.read();
      // msg += tmp;
     if( tmp!='\r' && tmp!='\n' ) msg+=tmp; // Does not work either
    }
    msg.replace(" ","");
    if (msg=="G") {
      stepperOne();
      Serial.println("Stepper turned.");
    }
    Serial.flush();
  }
}

void stepperOne() {

  AccelStepper stepper(1,stepPin,dirPin);
  digitalWrite(enPin,LOW);
  stepper.setMaxSpeed(SPD);
  stepper.setAcceleration(ACCEL);
  stepper.move(DEST);
  if (DEST > 0) {
    while ( stepper.distanceToGo() > 0 ) {
      stepper.run();
      }
  digitalWrite(enPin,HIGH);
  }
 }
```

Comment: It you type "G" in the serial console, it will send "G\r\n" (with an "enter" at the end). Your code doesn't account for the carriage return and newline at the end.

Comment: How can I account for carriage return ?

Comment: You could opt to ignore it. `if( tmp!='\r' && tmp!='\n' ) msg+=tmp;`

Comment: Thanks. I added it in the code (see above) and it still does not work. Serial works though. I am confused.

Comment: Stupid question can the Arduino version (older Uno) be the reason for this ? Or am I missing something ? Thanks

Comment: does the stepper work without the Serial code?

Comment: The serial.println works so I guess the Serial port works.

Comment: I found the solution, it was the Arduino, older version R2, the R3 works like a charm. I didn't know that the version could cause so much trouble. Sorry.

Comment: Write this as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it was the Arduino, older version R2, the R3 works like a charm. I didn't know that the version could cause so much trouble. But in case someone encounters the same problem R3 did it for me.